# Random value calculation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, random

Is there a way to do a random value calculation within a range in QGIS?

I have been able to do this within ArcMap Field Calculator with the following code:

```
Dim max, min
max=20
min=5
x=(Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min))

__esri_field_calculator_splitter__
x
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While QGIS doesn't appear to have this functionality, you may be able to work "around" it.

If you export your data to a SpatiaLite database you can then use the `random()` from [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) in an SQL statement.
I guess something like this:

`update TABLE set COLUMN = ROUND((20-5+1) * random() + 5)`

Any other database would do too, but that one can be treated as a local file and doesn't require installation of something seperate.

Answer (score 13):

QGIS 2.4+ has a couple of random number functions:

```
rand(min,max) # returns a random integer between min and max, inclusive

randf(min,max) # returns a float value.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could load the DBF into OO/Libre Office Calc and do this there. I think you need to have Base installed for Calc to be able to work with DBFs and you'd need to set the headers for columns that you create appropriately for data-type, field width, precision and so on. I quite often work on shapefile DBFs in Calc and have never had problems doing this, it's very convenient.